# How to modify captions of windows created by visual studio project wizard

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, project, wizard

I have craeted a Visual C++ project using studio 2010 wizard in which I have added things like FileView, ClassView, PropertiesWindow, OutputWindow etc, with the help of wizard. Now I am interested in changing the default captions/names of one of these items let's say FileView. The FileView has a resource string "IDS_FILE_VIEW" associated with it with value "File View" which is displayed as a caption of the FileView window. If I change the value of above mentioned string in the resources it does not change that caption and still shows "File View" as a caption. Could anyone suggest me that how can I customize captions and other features of such common windows created through studio wizards?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say, but I assume from the "IDS" that you are using the MFC libraries.

In MFC, the resource strings like IDS_FILE_VIEW are defined and used by the designer but it is quite possible to override them. Changing the IDS_FILE_VIEW resource's value will indeed change what is displayed when that resource is used, but you may have (inadvertently) prevented that resource being used where you expect.

I would check through your project files to see where this and related names appear and verify that there are no inconsistencies.

HtH

Ruth